# Prevent viewport from moving when removing DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to implement an HTML infinite scroller in which at any given time there are only a handful of div elements on list (to keep the memory footprint small).

I append a new div element to the list and at the same time I'm removing the first one, so the total count of divs remains the same.

Unfortunately the viewport doesn't stay still but instead it jumps backwards a little bit (the height of the removed div actually).
Is there a way to keep the viewport still while removing divs from the list?

I made a small self contained HTML page (well, it still needs JQuery 3.4.1) which exposes the problem: it starts by adding 5 divs and then it keeps adding a new one and removing the first one every 1 second

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function removeit() {
  // remove first one
  var tiles = $(".tile");
  $(tiles[0]).remove();
}

function addit() {
  // append new one
  var jqueryTextElem = $('<div class="tile" style="height:100px;background-color:' + getRandomColor() + '"></div>');
  $("#inner-wrap").append(jqueryTextElem);
}

function loop() {
  removeit();

  addit();

  window.setTimeout(loop, 1000);
}

addit();
addit();
addit();
addit();
addit();

loop();
```

```html
<div id="inner-wrap"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you remove top `div` guess what's the new top `div`? the next one, forcing browser to re-paint and thus the jumping effect. IMO, You are making browser do more work you should keep the outer divs as is and you may remove internal stuff if you are more concerned on extra DOM elements.

Comment: @Rikin What I'm really trying to achieve is an infinite scroller in which I add one more div at the bottom and I remove the div on top, keeping the div count low. For the time being I will only deal with the scroll down. Next step will be going up, which means adding a new div on top and removing one at the bottom.

Comment: Yes so for that purpose you would have to preserve real-estate for the OLD divs unless you are not going to have scroll bar on the webpage in which case top div in the viewport is always first.

Comment: @Rikin Interesting, could you please elaborate more or fix the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can temporarily add `position: fixed` to the parent element:

1. first add `position: fixed` to the parent;
2. then remove the item;
3. then remove `position: fixed` from the parent

Comment: how does this work? Adding position:fixed removes the parent element from view

Comment: @mss - I hope I can help but, first, I need to clarify your question. Are you saying: "This approach isn't working for me" or are you saying: "I see this approach is working but _how_ is it working?"

Comment: Both. This approach apparently isn't working for me but since this answer is marked as accepted it seems this approach worked for OP so I am curious how does this approach work, after knowing that maybe be I'll be able to make this approach work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you're trying to have your cake and eat it, in that if you get the viewport to be "still", I think you're meaning you don't want a user to see the scrollbar move and then also not have any new affordance to scroll further down the page, because you would want the scrollbar thumb/grabber to still sit at the bottom of the scrollbar track?

I mean, you could just use `$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + 100);` in your example to make it so the scroll position of the viewport won't visually move when removing elements, but at that point, you wouldn't be keeping the users view of the current elements the same or even allowing a user to have new content further down the page to scroll towards. You'd just be "pushing up" content through the view of the user?

If you are trying to lighten the load of what is currently parsed into document because you are doing some heavy lifting on the document object at runtime, maybe you still want to remove earlier elements, but retain their geometry with some empty sentinel element that always has the height of all previously removed elements added to it? This would allow you to both have a somewhat smaller footprint (though not layout-wise), while still having a usable scrollbar that can communicate to a user and both allow a user to scroll down, towards the content that has been added in.

All in all, I think what you currently have is how most infinite scrollers do and should work, meaning the scroll position and scrollbar should change when content is added in the direction the user is scrolling towards, this communicates to them that they can in fact keep scrolling that way. You really shouldn't want the viewports scroll position to be "still".

To see more clearly why I don't think you have an actual issue, replace your `loop()` definition with something like this...

```
function loop() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    // check for reaching bottom of scroller
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
      addit();
      removeit();
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Actually, here's a decent reference that was just written, though it's talking about a react version of this, it lays out out how/why these things work the way they do.
https://web.dev/virtualize-long-lists-react-window/